# Getting Datas from API A, B, C and Pushing them to API X

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I've been tinkering a bit with Azure Data bricks and Azure data factory, and I was wondering if these were overkill when you just want to take datas from a few Services by calling these services API (Rest), and then pushing these datas to a Service X using a Rest API as well.

I've seen that the Data factory can call a rest API (but does not seem to support Oauth2), but I have not found anything about pushing the datas to another rest Api (And it doesnt really makes sens to consolidate everything in an Azure DB at this point)

So, should I use the data factory, or writing a python script and calling it with Azure Functions would be more suited to solve this problem ?

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to use DataFactory only when the data can be moved quite straightforward from one DB (or file) to another DB. When you need more logic to interact with an API such as in your case there is little additional value in using DataFactory since you already need some compute (such as Azure Functions).

If your ingestion of data is some sort of workflow (e.g. you need A, B and C in a specific order before you can push to X) then I can recommend using [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview) with function chaining and fan-out/fan-in patterns. I also have some [video content](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARhgG7OeoX0&t=586s) where I explain this.

Here a small pseudo code example of an orchestration using function chaining:

```
var id = input.GetInput<string>();
var a = await context.CallActivityAsync<DataA>("CallApiAActivity", id);
var b = await context.CallActivityAsync<DataB>("CallApiBActivity", id);
var c = await context.CallActivityAsync<DataC>("CallApiCActivity", id);
var combined = Builder.CombineABC(a, b, c);

return  await context.CallActivityAsync<bool>("PushToApiXActivity", combined);
```

If the calls to A, B and C are unrelated then I suggest you do a fan-out/fan-in so these functions can be called in parallel.

The benefit of Durable Functions is that the orchestration is stateful and does checkpointing to storage for each activity function call. This enables automatic retries by using the `CallActivityWithRetryAsync` method. This is especially useful when dealing with services out of your control and makes your solution more resilient.